# Alternative to groupby + cumprod (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, quantitative-finance

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnKtW.png)

I have the above dataframe, which shows Assets A, B ...Z's MONTHLY return +1.

I need to find the cumulative product for each year, meaning i want to find the sum of product of monthly returns, annually.

I've been using:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year).cumproduct()
```

But this cannot work as cumproduct isn't an aggregator. Can someone suggest another method? Whether is using for loop to multiply or something..

Thank you!!

Comment: provide minimal dataset with expected output

Comment: You wrote *sum of product*. Please explain: 1. What is the source to *cumproduct*. 2. How do you want to sum the above results.

Answer (score 0):

To present a concise example, I took the source DataFrame as:

```
             Agric    Food
Date                      
1970-01-01  1.0083  0.9719
1970-02-01  1.0948  1.0596
1970-03-01  0.8672  0.9939
1970-04-01  0.8236  0.8943
1971-01-01  1.0070  0.9019
1971-02-01  1.0748  1.0006
1971-03-01  0.7672  0.8939
1971-04-01  0.7236  0.7943
```

(just 2 columns, for 2 years and only 4 months).

To compute cumulative sum for each column, within each year,
you can run:

```
result = df.groupby(df.index.year).cumprod()
```

Note that the function needed is named *cumprod*, not *cumproduct*.

The result is:

```
               Agric      Food
Date                          
1970-01-01  1.008300  0.971900
1970-02-01  1.103887  1.029825
1970-03-01  0.957291  1.023543
1970-04-01  0.788425  0.915355
1971-01-01  1.007000  0.901900
1971-02-01  1.082324  0.902441
1971-03-01  0.830359  0.806692
1971-04-01  0.600848  0.640756
```

But it is not clear what you want to sum.